# symfony2.8 assets in PRO mode not working

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with assets in PRO mode.
See console: http://paradasym85.alwaysdata.net/web/

If in my machine I switch DEV mode for PRO mode, JS joining is not working.

Is there any way to have the static function in the same manner as in DEV?

I already tried `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you cleared cache (with `--env=prod` flag), dumped assets and dumped assetic files? Check [this list](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) of things to do when moving to production.

Comment: yes, php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup. all work correctly but js by joining does not work correctly.

Comment: Improved English and formatting

Comment: ... and you've dumped assets & asset (`assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` & `assets:install`)?